# How do you pronounce the word 'vagary'?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm a native speaker, and I would naturally read the word VAY-guh-ri.

I've never actually heard anyone say the word, I only ever see it in writing.

But I also know that you can pronounce it vuh-GARE-i.  Does anyone actually pronounce it like this?  Where does this weird pronunciation come from?

Comment: I've never heard the latter either. The [Wiktionary article](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vagary) agrees with "formerly /ˌvəˈɡɛɹi/, now commonly /ˈveɪˌɡəɹi/".

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary gives /ˈveɪˌɡəɹi/ first, /ˌvəˈɡɛɹi/ second (never heard /ˌvəˈɡɛɹi/ myself).

Comment: I've never heard this pronounced vuh-GARE-i - so as far as *I'm* concerned this pronunciation came from ***you***!

Comment: W.S.Gilbert's "Iolanthe" (1882) requires the second: "A plague on this vagary / I'm in a nice quandary / .. " going on to rhyme it with "chary", "fairy", "library" and "seminary". Of course, some of the other rhyming words need unconventional pronunciations too.

Comment: Word power made easy by Norman Lewis says the word is va-GARE-ee and I was pleasantly surprised, but this is a pretty old book where secretive is se-KREE-tive, so I'm not so sure

Comment: there are two different words spelled "secretive"—one has to do with secrets, the other with secretions.

Comment: @Cerberus: wouldn't it be /vəˈɡɛ**ə**rɪ/? It has the MARY vowel, not the MERRY vowel, for people who distinguish the two.

Comment: My Irish mother in law used the latter pronounciation. She had heard it used when she was a parlour maid in London in the 20's and 30's.Eaton Place etc.

Comment: @user111494 My sister was visiting and yesterday she mentioned "se KREE ting something away". So that is still in use in England. Never heard of ve GARE ee, though.

Answer (score 5):

It used to be pronounced vuh-GARE-i, but it's changed. As @Tim above stated:

> (GenAm) IPA: formerly /ˌvəˈɡɛɹi/, now commonly /ˈveɪˌɡəɹi/

It's usually pronounced VAY -guh-ri, but there are still people who pronounce it the "other way", as can be [seen here](http://wordcraft.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/932607094/m/9406060772?r=387105219#387105219)

Answer (score 1):

In Gilbert and Sullivan's *Iolanthe* (1882) the old pronunciation definitely held:

> We are dainty little fairies
>   Ever singing, ever dancing;
>   We indulge in our vagaries
>   In a fashion most entrancing.

I have to admit that since 1882 lyricists seem generally to have fought shy of using *vagaries* in their rhyme-schemes, so as a way of dating pronunciation-change, it's a bit lacking.

Answer (score 0):

"Vagary" is one of a number of words from Latin or Romance languages that had a long, stressed vowel in the second-to-last syllable in the source language, but that can be pronounced in present-day English with the stress shifted to the third-to-last syllable.

The Oxford English Dictionary says "probably < Latin *vagārī* (Italian *vagare*) to wander". (Italian "vagare" is pronounced [vaˈgaːre].)

Other words like *vagary* that used to be pronounced with stress on the second syllable (some still can be) are *balcony* (< Italian *balcone* [balˈkoːne]), *abdomen* (< Latin *abdōmen*) and *acumen* (< Latin *acūmen*).

While the etymology somewhat explains the existence of the variant with stress on the second-to-last syllable, there are also words with somewhat similar etymology where as far as I know the stress has been on the third-to-last syllable for much longer, such as *plethora* (< Greek *πληθώρα,* its derivative Latin *plethora,* and its derivative French *pléthore*; the OED says "In 18th-cent. dictionaries the word is occasionally recorded with stress on the second syllable (Bailey (1731, 1735)), apparently following the ancient Greek stress") and *retina* (< Latin *retina,* with the suffix *-ina* that had a long "ī" in Classical Latin).