# Silent-letter U in the word Vagueries

Tags: silent-letters

When pronouncing the word *vagueries,* is the U silent or pronounced as in the British pronunciation of *jaguar*?

The context is the sentence ”The rebuttal was replete with so many vagueries as to be utterly unsubstantiated.”

Comment: @sumelic: it's in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaguery#English). Of course, that doesn't mean it's a real word.

Comment: @PeterShor Sigh. Wiktionary is not a trustworthy site. If 'vaguery' is in fact found in the literature, it is  obsolete, and Wiktionary gives no such indication.

Comment: @Mitch: Wiktionary gives citations, the most recent of which is from 2003. I don't think "obsolete" would be an appropriate description. It just seems to be very rare, and probably has been so from the beginning. Obviously it's possible to object to its use, but it doesn't look like it's a hoax word or an unattested word. Wordnik provides more examples: https://www.wordnik.com/words/vaguery

Comment: @sumelic it's not standard then, would be changed by any editor to 'vagaries'.

Comment: @Mitch: or *vaguenesses*, which is what Wiktionary says it means when it's not an error for *vagaries*.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't know what to think anymore

Comment: In any case, the question asks how to pronounce the "u" in the word. Null case.

Comment: Yes, thank you all. Clearly, as sumelic suggests any editor would make a change to vagaries.  PeterShor, the sentence read ”The rebuttal was replete with so many vagueries as to be utterly unsubstantiated.”

Answer (score 1):

"Vaguery" is an uncommon word, so I haven't been able to find any sources that give its pronunciation. Nevertheless, it can be inferred that it is pronounced /ˈveɪgəri/ (and so the plural "vagueries" would be pronounced /ˈveɪgəriz/). The U would not be "pronounced" any more than it is in the base adjective *vague.*

Evidence:

1. The more common word *vagary* is often pronounced /ˈveɪgəri/ (although in the past, a different [pronunciation with stress on the second syllable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32862/how-do-you-pronounce-the-word-vagary) was used) and the spelling "vaguery" seems in some cases to be used as a (nonstandard) representation of this word. In a comment, Peter Shor linked to the Wiktionary entry for *[vaguery](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaguery#English)*, which is as follows:

   > 1. (uncountable) Vagueness, the condition of being vague.
   > 2. (countable) A vagueness, a thing which is vague, an example of vagueness.
   > 3. (countable, in the plural) An [eggcorn](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggcorn#English) for vagaries.

   Wiktionary gives a few example quotations for each usage (incidentally, the quotations for 1) and 2), along with the examples from [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/vaguery), also illustrate that "vaguery" is not *only* used as a misspelling of *vagary,* in case anyone else thought that when first viewing this question).
2. The addition of the suffix *-ery* regularly adds /əri/ (optionally reduced to just /ri/ for some speakers by the process of schwa syncope) to the pronunciation of the base word. It doesn't cause a "silent" U in the spelling of the base word to become pronounced. Compare the word *roguery,* which is pronounced as /roʊgəri/ ([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=roguery), [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roguery), [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/roguery)).